# Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, instantiation

I am facing this problem in Unity again and again. I cannot find solution.
I think my code is right, but where is the problem?

```
GameObject visual = Instantiate<GameObject>(placementObject[num], hit.point + visualOffset, Quaternion.identity); 
visual.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform); <--- Causing error
```

Any suggestions? Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: Why not use the option to specify parent at instantiation?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem using the information in the question. Please include steps on how to produce the problem starting from a blank project including how to assign prefabs to `placementObject`, how to create those prefabs, etc. See [mre] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set the parent directly:

```
GameObject visual = Instantiate<GameObject>(placementObject[num], hit.point + visualOffset, Quaternion.identity, parentObject.transform);
```

but using SetParent after Instantiate() should work, too.
Check whether parentObject is not null.

Comment: Error: Cannot instantiate objects with a parent which is persistent. New object will be created without a parent.
UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate(GameObject, Vector3, Quaternion, Transform)
ObjectPlacement:Placing() (at Assets/ObjectPlacement.cs:80)
ObjectPlacement:Update() (at Assets/ObjectPlacement.cs:60)

At line 60 and 80 is the same row ->Visual.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that, i was using a prefab linked in different script and i do not noticed! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign a parent that is a prefab and not an instance of an object in your scene.

Ensure that `parentObject` is an actual object and not a prefab (or, if you're editing a prefab, ensure that it is an actual object *within* that prefab, and not an unreferenced prefab itself).

Comment: holy crap thank you, this answer was so difficult to find! I forgot I assigned a prefab instead of a gameobject and this error message is god-awful for diagnosing the issue.